# Most Efficient Way to Check Collisions in didBeginContact

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

What's the best way to check for collision using SpriteKit's `didBeginContact` method. I'm currently checking by class and doing something like this:

```
if let thisMine = nodeA as? Mine {
    if nodeB is Player {
       thisMine.explode()
   }
}
else if let thisMine = nodeB as? Mine {
    if nodeA is Player {
       thisMine.explode()
   }
}
```

I'm doing this a bunch of times in the `didBeginContact` method because I have lots of different objects that can interact with each other. Is it more efficient to be checking by the bit masks? Also, is there a way to cut down on needing to basically duplicate all the code by checking nodeA and nodeB as the same class?

Comment: SO frowns upon asking 2 questions in one post. You would be better off asking this as a new question - post your code using both approaches and ask which is the 'preferred technique'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use category bitMasks:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

        switch contactMask {

        case categoryBitMask.player | categoryBitMask.thisMine:
           print("Collision between player and thisMine")
           let mineNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == categoryBitMask.thisMine ? contact.bodyA.node! : contact.bodyB.node!
           mineNode.explode()

        default :
           //Some other contact has occurred
           print("Some other contact")
    }  
}
```