# Detecting Collisions Efficiently

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I've tried a couple different methods for detecting collisions in the didBeginContact method, but I'm not sure which one is more efficient - I'm trying to cut down on my frame rate drops.

Method 1:

```
if let thisMine = nodeA as? Mine {
        if let thisPlayer = nodeB as? Player {
           thisMine.explode()
           thisPlayer.takeDamage(thisMine.damage)
       }
    }
    else if let thisMine = nodeB as? Mine {
        if let thisPlayer = nodeA as? Player {
           thisMine.explode()
           thisPlayer.takeDamage(thisMine.damage)
       }
    }
```

I'm doing this a bunch of times using different classes in the didBeginContact method because I have lots of different objects that can interact with each other.

Method 2 (Suggested by Steve Ives with modifications):

```
let contactMask = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask

    switch contactMask {

    case CollisionCategoryPlayer | CollisionCategoryMine:
       let mineNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryMine ? contact.bodyA.node as! Mine : contact.bodyB.node as! Mine
       let playerNode = contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == CollisionCategoryPlayer  ? contact.bodyA.node as! Player : contact.bodyB.node as! Player

       mineNode.explode()
       playerNode.takeDamage(mineNode.damage)

    default :
       print("Unregistered contact")
}
```

With this method, I have to cast the contact body nodes as a player/mine/other class in order to access their properties and functions. Is this still more efficient than comparing the node's classes like in method 1? I imagine it's more efficient to use the switch statement rather than a bunch of if statements?

Note: this is a follow up question to [Most Efficient Way to Check Collisions in didBeginContact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37996254/most-efficient-way-to-check-collisions-in-didbegincontact?noredirect=1#comment63551122_37996254)

Comment: "Best practice" questions are not fit for stack overflow, perhaps try asking the code review exchange. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  Note: you need to ask `Does this code follow best practice?`, not `What is the best practice?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely go with method 2 if collisions occur frequently or if there are more than these two classes.

The reasons for this are very obvious: The `or`-operation and your switch statement here can be performed in constant time. Whereas the `as?` operator could perform at `O(n)` or `O(log2(n))` (completely depends on whatever the Swift Runtime Environment employs, `O(1)`, however, is very unlikely).

If you want performant code and objects collide often, go with two. If objects collide very rarely however and you prefer very clear code, method one might be an option.

Comment: doesn't code 2 perform the same types of checks as code 1, with the addition of a switch and or

Comment: Thanks for the response. Does the same hold true for when I cast using the as! instead of as? Since I'm needing to cast to a class using as! to access the properties/functions, will that ruin the performance of method 2?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon That’s right. But these checks (they are likely removed in release mode because of the `!`) are only performed if the collision is actually of interest whereas in code 1 these checks are performed every time two objects collide.

Comment: @claassenApps As long as there are many different objects colliding and you’re only interested in a few particular cases this might be more efficient. In this case `as!` inside the `switch` is likely more efficient. It depends on the ratio of *didBeginContact called* / *switch case entered*. That’s fine in theory, in practice, though, the difference is really minimal and we’re talking about micro-optimization.

Comment: Thank you both for your input.

Comment: Also bear in mind that for some collsions in games (this may not be applicable to your game), it is not necessary to determine if nodeA is the player, or if nodeB is the enemy etc - it is enough to know that the player and the enemy have collided so call player.explode() and decrease the score by 10 (for example). In this situation, there is no need to do anything with nodeA or nodeB.